# DBCL message on console

Tags: java, spring, logging, apache-commons-dbcp

I am creating a database connection pool with following properties.

```
<bean id="complianceCCRDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" 
        destroy-method="close" lazy-init="false" >

    <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" /> 
    <property name="username" value="${deshaw.compliance.ccr.db.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${deshaw.compliance.ccr.db.password}" />
    <property name="url" value="${deshaw.compliance.ccr.db.url}" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="60000"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" /> 
    <property name="validationQuery"> 
        <value>use ${deshaw.compliance.ccr.db.name} SELECT 1 
        </value> 
    </property>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="10" />
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
    <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="600" />
    <property name="logAbandoned" value="false" />
</bean>
```

When I try to instantiate the above bean, I am getting following messages on STDOUT. Is there any way I can suppress these ?

```
   AbandonedObjectPool is used (org.apache.commons.dbcp.AbandonedObjectPool@2d82ef6b)
   LogAbandoned: false
   RemoveAbandoned: true
   RemoveAbandonedTimeout: 600
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `setLogWriter()` (see javadoc [here](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/api-1.2.2/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html#setLogWriter%28java.io.PrintWriter%29)) method as described in this [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DBCP-194).